# How to implement Sentry on Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, errors, debug

I need Sentry to track errors in my project code, the unofficial plugin for wordpress seems to be useless. How should I fix it?

Comment: 3rd party plugin support is offtopic, you should contact the plugin authors to fix/add JS support, or, consult Sentry docs on how to add it

Answer (score 3):

For php I used this guide: https://cloudpresshosting.co.uk/blog/reporting-wordpress-errors-to-sentry

For JS, I found out I can take the code of the bundle and the initialization and put in the header, using "add scripts to header and footer" plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts
It took me time to notice I can't put the initialization within the bundle import.
Got something like this:

```
<script
  src="https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/5.20.1/bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-O8HdAJg1h8RARFowXd2J/r5fIWuinSBtjhwQoPesfVILeXzGpJxvyY/77OaPPXUo"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
Sentry.init({ dsn: 'https://unique@unique' });
</script>
```